# Java Homework Assignment — java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, exception

I get an error from automated JUnit 4 unit testing software that my course instructor uses to automatically check assignments.

We upload our draft code to a cloud program tester which automatically checks and grades the assignments.

This is week 1 of first semester. I've never coded in Java before. And the lessons haven't taught if/else, while, loops, switch etc. so I don't think it's okay to use those (they appear next module.)

I followed a class video tutorial, which doesn't throw any exceptions in the tutorial — so I don't know what's going on.

The unit was on variables, input, printing out, Booleans, operators, and a few things like contains, replace, equals etc.

Note: I am allowed to ask questions on StackOverflow per instructor.

**The error is: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found**

No line number is specified in the testing software where the exception occurs. And since it's not happening in my IDE, I don't know where it is.

Other solutions I've found require while and other methods I'm not supposed to use.

My code (below) runs okay in the VSCODE IDE cloud the school provided.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContainsAnyCase {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type a word:\n");

    Scanner userInputWord = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = userInputWord.nextLine();

    String wordlc = word.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println("Type a sentence:\n");

    Scanner userInputSentence = new Scanner(System.in);

    String sentence = userInputSentence.nextLine();

    String sentencelc = sentence.toLowerCase();

    boolean isContains = sentencelc.contains(wordlc);

    System.out.println(isContains);

  }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone can explain why there is an error and if there are ways to fix it or avoid the error without going into the territory of future modules? Also, I'm still learning how to use Stack Overflow appropriately. If I asked my question wrong, please advise how I can improve my question or post. Thank you.

I expected for the program to tell me true/false if the word was in the sentence. In my IDE, it worked. When I uploaded it to the JUnit4, it said java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Comment: Don't create multiple scanners. Just create one, and call nextLine twice.

Comment: Actually, does JUnit4 let you access System.in? I don't know what you mean by "When I uploaded it to the JUnit4". This error seems to be caused when System.in gets closed. When using JUnit4 you might not get a System.in at all. Which line throws the exception?

Comment: For completeness' sake: exception are thrown at _runtime_, which happens after compilations. Code might compile fine, but still have all sorts of problems and bugs. (How great would it be if code that compiled meant that it works and doesn't have bugs? One can dream …)

Comment: I updated the post with a few more details. When I refer to uploading, I mean that students are to upload their draft/finished code to a cloud application-> automated "assignment tester & grading" software that uses JUnit4. So the cloud application I'm uploading to is what checks my code. But since it has this error, it won't even run the test. It won't show a line number for the error, and my IDE isn't showing it at all either.

I'm not sure how to "Don't create multiple scanners" but I will look that up.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to "Don't create multiple scanners": you're creating a scanner twice, instead of creating one and call nextLine two times on the *same* Scanner. This is  what @matt meant.

Comment: Since you cannot see the correct stacktrace, it's impossible for you to tell which class is missing in the "cloud's java". I suggest you try -if possible- to upload a simple hello world first, and then start adding line by line (where it makes sense) to see which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using just ONE SCANNER as suggested in the comments.

I've also eliminated the second set of variables for lower case; just convert the input directly to lower case and store it in the original variable:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Type a word:\n");    
    String word = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    System.out.println("Type a sentence:\n");
    String sentence = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    boolean isContains = sentence.contains(word);
    System.out.println(isContains);
  }
```

If you need to preserve the exact user input for later, then you can convert to lower case only when you call contains() like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Type a word:\n");    
    String word = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Type a sentence:\n");
    String sentence = sc.nextLine();

    boolean isContains = sentence.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println(isContains);
  }
```

Comment: "isContains" gives me Enterprise vibes ;) I'd have called the variable 'contains' or 'isContained' ;)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Haha!...I just copied their variable name. I would have called it `containsWord` myself.  =)

Comment: Sorry for "Enterprise Vibes" haha. Is that bad? I'm still learning. =) Thanks for the help! I will give it a try now.

Comment: Enterprise Vibes normally refers to the over-complication of what would otherwise be a "relatively straightforward" approach. The "joke" is better represented by the famous [Fizz Buzz Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) where a simple "fizz buzz" exercise is designed as an "enterprise" piece of software, with an insane amount of patterns and abstractions that make it a huge project, to the point of ridiculousness ;) Anyway, keep learning and good luck! Idle_mind example is good, hopefully you can understand the difference with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. And yes, it worked. I figured it out and all 7 of my files (including this one posted) that had the error is fixed now and passing the tests. It all seemed related to either using more than one new scanner, or not closing. Sometimes it was better to close before making a new one. Sometimes it was better to only use one more than once. Thanks everyone for the help.